# Game have an initial jerk when JSON levels are loaded-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I have about 25 levels in my game,and each one will get loaded automatically when previous one has completed.
When I click play button to start the game,game screen is getting loaded with obstacles from JSON. But there is a jerk happening initially when game is just start playing.

This is my class where I am doing JSON parsing for the levels :

```
public class ObstacleFactory {

    public static Array<Obstacle> obstacles1 = new Array<Obstacle>();
    public static Array<String> names = new Array<String>();

    public ObstacleFactory() {
    }

    public static void loadJsonLevels(String fileName) {
        JsonValue jsonValue = new JsonReader().parse(Gdx.files.internal(fileName));
        JsonValue nameValue = jsonValue.get("obstacles");
        for (JsonValue value : nameValue.iterator()) {

            System.out.println(nameValue);

            if (value.getString("name").equals("rock")) {
                obstacles1.add(new Obstacle());
                obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setName(value.getString("name"));
                obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setDistance(value.getFloat("distance"));
                obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setPos(value.getString("position"));
                obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setSpeed(value.getFloat("speed"));
                if (value.getString("position").equals("middle"))
                    obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setPosition(value.getFloat("distance"), Constants.BIG_ROCK_Y);
                obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setSize(Constants.ROCK_WIDTH, Constants.ROCK_HEIGHT);

                names.add(value.getString("name"));
            }
            if (value.getString("name").equals("gorilla")) {
                obstacles1.add(new Obstacle());
                obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setName(value.getString("name"));
                obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setDistance(value.getFloat("distance"));
                obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setPos(value.getString("position"));
                obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setSpeed(value.getFloat("speed"));
                if (value.getString("position").equals("middle"))
                    obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setPosition(value.getFloat("distance"), Constants.GORILLA_Y);
                obstacles1.get(obstacles1.size - 1).setSize(Constants.GORILLA_WIDTH, Constants.GORILLA_HEIGHT);

                names.add(value.getString("name"));

            }
     //   ------------other obstacles
      //  -------------other obstacles

                names.add(value.getString("name"));
            }
        }
      }
     }
```

This loadJsonLevels() I am calling in GameScreen class(where I am writing all the gamelogic,and texture loading for the obstacles from JSON and other game object.)constructor like this:

```
ObstacleFactory.loadJsonLevels("levels/level1.json");
ObstacleFactory.loadJsonLevels("levels/level2.json");
```

Every time I starts,or restarts the game,this jerk is there and should be removed because it is annoying.

What are the possible reasons for this issue?

I posted code related to json parsing and level loading because this jerk happening when I call this loadJsonLevel().If I comment it,jerk is not there.

I hope I will be able to get some useful suggestion to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably starting to show the screen before the data has been fully loaded.

It's a pretty expensive operation (or can be, especially on low resource devices) to open, read, and write files or networks.
You don't want to do that in your main display thread, and you don't want to do it while the screen is being drawn.
Good reason for that cut scene or something else to keep the user waiting for a few seconds.